# Updating with drop down Array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Update through the drop down is not working. I have a `form_tag` inside the form tag I have the loop. So, the value will pass in an array. How can I update the value from it.

In my Period controller I have

```
def period
 @period = Period.all
end

def period_update
 Period.update(perio_params)
end

private
 def perio_params
   params.require([:period][:subject_id]).permit(:subject_id)
 end
```

In the period_update views I have

```
<%= form_tag perio_update_institutes_path, method: :put do  %>
<% @period.each do |p|%> 
    <%= p.subject.name %>
<%= select_tag('subject_id', options_for_select(Subject.all.collect{ |s| [s.name, s.id]}), {prompt: 'Select Sub'})%>

<%end%>
<%= submit_tag %>
```

`{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"6LJrh2ct7VMGU6Siq/RXIMGz4kkxkVN81Jqa+eRcKb3rXq3XzBlv8gjHvjjVsPsJ4LF7ZEHF/GQ8+0906lhyUg==",
 "period"=>{"subject_id"=>["2",
 "2"]},
 "commit"=>"Save changes"}`

how can I update the subject_id array.

The ERROR is

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

I have the subject model, where all the subject will be in the collection.
The Period model has the `subject_id`. How can I update.
I am new to rails, and I am stuck with this. Thank you for advance.

Comment: Why you have commented that part of the code?

Comment: oh sorry, I tried with the different syntax, when I paste here I did'nt notice that, I have tried the syntax like
`<%= collection_select(s, s.id, Subject.all, :id, :name, selected: s.id, prompt: true) %>`

Comment: You have a space between the identifier and the method call: `@period .each`. Which will cause an error. You should most likely be using `collection_select('some_key', 'subject_id', Subject.all, :id, :name, selected: s.id, prompt: true)`. But its impossible to figure out what you are actually trying to do without knowing more about your controller since this is pretty ideosyncratic.

Answer (score 0):

Try if it behaves differently with [options_from_collection_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select):

```
<%= select_tag('subject_id', options_from_collection_for_select(Subject.all, :id, :name), {prompt: 'Select Sub'}) %>
```